# Is it possible to create a graph using MatPlotLib with data from a scientific model?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, plot

To preface, I am completely new to Python and MatPlotLib, and I am working on a school project to calculate the trajectory of a satellite around the earth. I was wondering if it was possible to grab the data from every point the model calculates and put it inside the graph, plotting time on the x-axis and height on the y-axis. I tried to directly plot the two values, but it doesn't seem to appear on the graph. Is it possible to put every value from the calculations in the graph, or will I need to have a direct formula for the line to plot it in a graph.

The air resistance also changes for certain heights, so it makes it harder to make a direct formula. Here's the code, I am aware it is terribly formatted but it being my first project all I need from it is to get a t,h-graph. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
from typing import Any, Union

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = []
t = 0
dt = 10

A = 10
Cw = 2.7
h = 300000
h0 = h
G = 6.67384 * 10 ** -11
M = 5.972 * 10 ** 24
m = 209.4 * A ** (3 / 2)

r = 6371000 + h
v: Union[float, Any] = (G * M / r) ** .5

vx = v
vy = 0
Px = 0
Py = r

while 0 < h < h0 + 100000:
    # for _ in range(2592000):
    t = t + dt

    r = (Px ** 2 + Py ** 2) ** .5
    Fg = G * M * m / r ** 2
    Fgx = -Fg * Px / r
    Fgy = -Fg * Py / r

    h = r - 6371000
    if h > 600000:
        z = 1.607 * 10 ** -11 * 0.991169 ** (h / 1000)
    else:
        if h > 139000:
            z = 3.848 * 10 ** -8 * 0.978294 ** (h / 1000)
        else:
            z = 1.225 * 0.863697 ** (h / 1000)
    v = (vx ** 2 + vy ** 2) ** .5
    Fwl = 0.5 * z * Cw * A * v ** 2
    Fwlx = -Fwl * vx / v
    Fwly = -Fwl * vy / v

    ax = (Fgx + Fwlx) / m
    ay = (Fgy + Fwly) / m
    vx = vx + ax * dt
    vy = vy + ay * dt
    Px = Px + vx * dt
    Py = Py + vy * dt

data += [[h, t]]
print(h)
print(t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, h)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You are only plotting the last point `(t,h)`. Indent `data += [[h, t]]` one level to add every point in the while loop to `data`, then plot with `plt.plot(data)` (outside of the while loop). I suggest to reduce the while loop to `<h0 + 100`.

Comment: That works, thanks alot. One more small question though, when I run the program I get the graph but it has an x=y orange line on it in addition to the new correct line. Is there something unnecessary in my code I can get rid of to remove this line, or is it just something I'll have to live with?

Comment: One line are the values for `h`, the other (`x=y`) are the values for `t`. That is how `plt.plot` 'understands' your `data`. Please search for tutorials for matplotlib online or ask another question on stackoverflow if you can't find a way to get the plot you want. A fast fix would be `data += [[h]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Michael Szczesny in the comment, you should indent `data += [[h, t]]` within the `while` loop.
Then I suggest you to plot with:

```
ax.plot(*zip(*data))
```

in order to separate `h` for `t` and get `h(t)` curve.
An other suggestion is to flip the order in which you store `h` and `t` in `data`:

```
data += [[h, t]]
```

in this way you will get a plot of the height with respect to time (and not the inverse).

### Complete Code

```
from typing import Any, Union
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = []
t = 0
dt = 10

A = 10
Cw = 2.7
h = 300000
h0 = h
G = 6.67384 * 10 ** -11
M = 5.972 * 10 ** 24
m = 209.4 * A ** (3 / 2)

r = 6371000 + h
v: Union[float, Any] = (G * M / r) ** .5

vx = v
vy = 0
Px = 0
Py = r

while 0 < h < h0 + 100000:
    # for _ in range(2592000):
    t = t + dt

    r = (Px ** 2 + Py ** 2) ** .5
    Fg = G * M * m / r ** 2
    Fgx = -Fg * Px / r
    Fgy = -Fg * Py / r

    h = r - 6371000
    if h > 600000:
        z = 1.607 * 10 ** -11 * 0.991169 ** (h / 1000)
    else:
        if h > 139000:
            z = 3.848 * 10 ** -8 * 0.978294 ** (h / 1000)
        else:
            z = 1.225 * 0.863697 ** (h / 1000)
    v = (vx ** 2 + vy ** 2) ** .5
    Fwl = 0.5 * z * Cw * A * v ** 2
    Fwlx = -Fwl * vx / v
    Fwly = -Fwl * vy / v

    ax = (Fgx + Fwlx) / m
    ay = (Fgy + Fwly) / m
    vx = vx + ax * dt
    vy = vy + ay * dt
    Px = Px + vx * dt
    Py = Py + vy * dt

    data += [[h, t]]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(*zip(*data))

plt.show()
```

[image]